# Livewire Flickity Conflict/Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am having issues rendering a dynamic slider built using [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/). I have a CRUD where I add/remove slider images to the database and load them instantly live on the page. I have the following code setup, when I add a new slider image using `addPhoto()` method, it is added but does not load on the page until I refresh the page.

1. Livewire and Flickity conflict with each other. If i remove `wire:ignore` from the blade template it loads the newly added photo but messes with the Flickity slider (of course livewire manipulates the DOM).
2. If i keep `wire:ignore` inside the blade template it does not load the newly added photo until i manually reload the page. I also tried the '$refresh' via listener but no luck.

Is there any solution or workaround for this issue?

```php
class ProfileEdit extends Component
{
    public $photos;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->loadPhotos();
    }

    public addPhoto()
    {
        // Add a new photo to database
        
        // And finally load photos again to get latest data
        $this->loadPhotos();
    }

    protected function loadPhotos()
    {
        $this->photos = load photos from database
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.carousel');
    }
}
```

```php
<div>
    <div wire:ignore x-data="carousel()" x-init="init()" x-ref="carousel">
        @foreach ($photos as $photo)
            <div wire:key="{{ $loop->index }}">
                
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <script>
       function carousel() {
            return {
                init() {
                    var flkty = new Flickity(this.$refs.carousel, {
                        // 
                    });
                },
            }
        } 
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

mount() is only ever called when the component is first mounted and will not be called again even when the component is refreshed or rerendered.

```
class ProfileEdit extends Component
```

{

```
public addPhoto()
{
    // Add a new photo to database
}

protected function loadPhotos()
{
    $photos = load photos from database
    return $photos;
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.carousel', [
    'photos' => $this->loadPhotos(),
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: I dont have any issue with NOT LOADING of latest data. I update the `public $photos` after every action that updates the database. `$this->loadPhotos();` gets and sets latest data.

Comment: I have these two problems.

1) Livewire and Flickity conflict with each other. If i remove wire:ignore from the blade template it loads the newly added photo but messes with the Flickity slider (of course livewire manipulates the DOM).

2) If I keep wire:ignore inside the blade template it does not load the newly added photo until I manually reload the page.